# Count number of matches of a regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to write a regex to count the number of spaces/tabs/newline in a chunk of text. So I naively wrote the following:-

```
numSpaces : function(text) { 
    return text.match(/\s/).length; 
}
```

For some unknown reasons it always returns `1`. What is the problem with the above statement? I have since solved the problem with the following:-

```
numSpaces : function(text) { 
    return (text.split(/\s/).length -1); 
}
```

Answer (score 255, accepted):

**tl;dr: Generic Pattern Counter**

```
// THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED
const count = (str) => {
  const re = /YOUR_PATTERN_HERE/g
  return ((str || '').match(re) || []).length
}
```

For those that arrived here looking for a generic way to count the number of occurrences of a regex pattern in a string, and don't want it to fail if there are zero occurrences, this code is what you need. Here's a demonstration:

```js
/*
 *  Example
 */

const count = (str) => {
  const re = /[a-z]{3}/g
  return ((str || '').match(re) || []).length
}

const str1 = 'abc, def, ghi'
const str2 = 'ABC, DEF, GHI'

console.log(`'${str1}' has ${count(str1)} occurrences of pattern '/[a-z]{3}/g'`)
console.log(`'${str2}' has ${count(str2)} occurrences of pattern '/[a-z]{3}/g'`)
```

**Original Answer**

The problem with your initial code is that you are missing the [global identifier](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml):

```
>>> 'hi there how are you'.match(/\s/g).length;
4
```

Without the `g` part of the regex it will only match the first occurrence and stop there.

Also note that your regex will count successive spaces twice:

```
>>> 'hi  there'.match(/\s/g).length;
2
```

If that is not desirable, you could do this:

```
>>> 'hi  there'.match(/\s+/g).length;
1
```

Comment: This works as long as you have at least one space in your input. Otherwise, match() annoyingly returns null.

Comment: sfink is right, you definitely want to check if match() returned null: `var result = text.match(/\s/g); return result ? result.length : 0;`

Comment: You can also protect against the null by using this construction: `( str.match(...) || [] ).length`

Comment: What's the problem with `('string'.match(/\s/g) || []).length` ?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira The difference is: if `str` is null, then `str.match()` will fail but `(str || '').match()` will not.

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23385429/1338292), you can use [`RegExp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to iterate over all matches and count each occurrence; the advantage is limited to memory only, because on the whole it's about 20% slower than using [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```
var re = /\s/g,
count = 0;

while (re.exec(text) !== null) {
    ++count;
}

return count;
```

Answer (score 11):

```
(('a a a').match(/b/g) || []).length; // 0
(('a a a').match(/a/g) || []).length; // 3
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/48195124/16777 but fixed to actually work in zero-results case.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a similar solution to @Paolo Bergantino's answer, but with modern operators. I'll explain below.

```js
    const matchCount = (str, re) => {
      return str?.match(re)?.length ?? 0;
    };

    // usage
    
    let numSpaces = matchCount(undefined, /\s/g);
    console.log(numSpaces); // 0
    numSpaces = matchCount("foobarbaz", /\s/g);
    console.log(numSpaces); // 0
    numSpaces = matchCount("foo bar baz", /\s/g);
    console.log(numSpaces); // 2
```

`?.` is the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). It allows you to chain calls as deep as you want without having to worry about whether there is an undefined/null along the way. Think of `str?.match(re)` as

```js
if (str !== undefined && str !== null) {
    return str.match(re);
} else {
    return undefined;
}
```

This is slightly different from @Paolo Bergantino's. Theirs is written like this: `(str || '')`. That means if `str` is *falsy*, return `''`. 0 is falsy. [document.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) is falsy. In my opinion, if someone were to pass those into this function as a string, it would probably be because of programmer error. Therefore, I'd rather be informed I'm doing something non-sensible than troubleshoot why I keep on getting a length of 0.

`??` is the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). Think of it as `||` but more specific. If the left hand side of `||` evaluates to *falsy*, it executes the right-hand side. But `??` only executes if the left-hand side is undefined or null.

Keep in mind, the nullish coalescing operator in `?.length ?? 0` will return the same thing as using `?.length || 0`. The difference is, if `length` returns 0, it won't execute the right-hand side... but the result is going to be 0 whether you use `||` or `??`.

Honestly, in this situation I would probably change it to `||` because more JavaScript developers are familiar with that operator. Maybe someone could enlighten me on benefits of `??` vs `||` in this situation, if any exist.

Lastly, I changed the signature so the function can be used for any regex.

Oh, and here is a typescript version:

```js
    const matchCount = (str: string, re: RegExp) => {
      return str?.match(re)?.length ?? 0;
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

`('my string'.match(/\s/g) || []).length;`

Comment: I think you put the `|| []` in the wrong place, it should be `('my string'.match(/\s/g) || []).length`

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly something that has a lot of traps. I was working with Paolo Bergantino's answer, and realising that even that has some limitations. I found working with string representations of dates a good place to quickly find some of the main problems. Start with an input string like this:
`'12-2-2019 5:1:48.670'`

and set up Paolo's function like this:

```
function count(re, str) {
    if (typeof re !== "string") {
        return 0;
    }
    re = (re === '.') ? ('\\' + re) : re;
    var cre = new RegExp(re, 'g');
    return ((str || '').match(cre) || []).length;
}
```

I wanted the regular expression to be passed in, so that the function is more reusable, secondly, I wanted the parameter to be a string, so that the client doesn't have to make the regex, but simply match on the string, like a standard string utility class method.

Now, here you can see that I'm dealing with issues with the input. With the following:

```
if (typeof re !== "string") {
    return 0;
}
```

I am ensuring that the input isn't anything like the literal `0`, `false`, `undefined`, or `null`, none of which are strings. Since these literals are not in the input string, there should be no matches, but it should match `'0'`, which is a string.

With the following:

```
re = (re === '.') ? ('\\' + re) : re;
```

I am dealing with the fact that the RegExp constructor will (I think, wrongly) interpret the string `'.'` as the all character matcher `\.\`

Finally, because I am using the RegExp constructor, I need to give it the global `'g'` flag so that it counts all matches, not just the first one, similar to the suggestions in other posts.

I realise that this is an extremely late answer, but it might be helpful to someone stumbling along here. BTW here's the TypeScript version:

```
function count(re: string, str: string): number {
    if (typeof re !== 'string') {
        return 0;
    }
    re = (re === '.') ? ('\\' + re) : re;
    const cre = new RegExp(re, 'g');    
    return ((str || '').match(cre) || []).length;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems well solved but I hadn't seen this version, which might be a bit more readable, and in-keeping with the style in some codebases:

```
const numberOfResults = [...str.matchAll(/YOUR_REGEX/g)].length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using modern syntax avoids the need to create a dummy array to count length 0

```
const countMatches = (exp, str) => str.match(exp)?.length ?? 0;
```

Must pass `exp` as `RegExp` and `str` as `String`.

Answer (score -2):

how about like this

```
function isint(str){
    if(str.match(/\d/g).length==str.length){
        return true;
    }
    else {
         return false
    }
}
```