# Get number of occurrences of a character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that devides some data using `','`. Now I want to count the occurences of `','` in that string.  I tried:

```
var match = string.match('/[,]/i');
```

But this gives me null If I try to get the length of the match array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you need to check the occurances of a simple pattern as "," then better don't use regular expressions.

Try:

```
var matchesCount = string.split(",").length - 1;
```

Comment: Off by one: if you want to count the occurences of "," you've to do -1

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lsauer/2757250 (mentioned in the answer lower down this page) suggests that split() is inefficient, and should be avoided on large strings.

Comment: I tried creating some benchmarks, looks like `split(',').length-1` is fastest. Can't speak for memory overhead though
https://run.perf.zone/view/Count-occurrences-of-single-char-in-a-string-1506617641964

Answer (score 5):

Remove the quotes and add the g flag:

```
var str = "This, is, another, word, followed, by, some, more";
var matches = str.match(/,/g);
alert(matches.length);    // 7
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/hG2NE/

Comment: good catch to remove the quotes, otherwise is a String and not a regular expression, but you've to use /g otherwise only the first match is returned. also /i is useless since there is no uppercase comma.

Comment: I've had g in my answer for awhile including in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Always like the jsfiddle links +1

Comment: @jfriend00 probably I loaded the page a while ago, and I was looking at the answers without refreshing it. I also edit often. +1 now that is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/lsauer/2757250) claimed that regexp was the most efficient technique.

***Edit:*** However the [performance benchmark](https://run.perf.zone/view/Count-occurrences-of-single-char-in-a-string-1506617641964) provided by [Job](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3211791/job) in the comments suggest that the `split` technique is now faster.  So I would recommend that nowadays.

But anyway, if you do go with the regexp approach, you should be aware that if there are no matches, then `String::match()` returns null, and not an empty array as you might expect:

```
> 'foo'.match(/o/g)
[ 'o', 'o' ]

> 'foo'.match(/o/g).length
2

> 'foo'.match(/x/g)
null

> 'foo'.match(/x/g).length
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

One simple way to deal with this is to substitute an empty array if the result is null:

```
var count = (string.match(/,/g) || []).length;
```

Or this avoids creating the empty array, but requires two lines of code:

```
var match = string.match(/,/g);
var count = match ? match.length : 0;
```

Comment: I made took (most of) the code in that gist and made a benchmark:

https://run.perf.zone/view/Count-occurrences-of-single-char-in-a-string-1506617641964

Looks like `split(',').length-1)` is currently faster by a *large* margin! On my machine it's 60x faster than the second option in Chrome, and 10x faster on Firefox. No idea about memory overhead though.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the perf. Perhaps the engine's efficiency with temporary objects has increased, so now the cost of creating a new regexp dominates. I wonder if the results would be any different if the regexp was defined only once and reused many times.

Comment: The regex version is still slower: https://run.perf.zone/view/Count-occurrences-of-single-char-in-a-string-v21-1516516301656

Answer (score 1):

[Count number of matches of a regex in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072765/count-number-of-matches-of-a-regex-in-javascript)

you need the `/g` global flag

Edit: I didn't need the 'ticks' below.

```
var count = string.match(/,/g).length;
```

Comment: Doesn't work with the quotes around the regex.

Comment: This doesn't work, tested in Firebug. "a,b".match('/,/g'); returns null

Comment: Oops... I didn't need the 'ticks' below.

Comment: You are right not to use `'`s around the regexp, and you are correct that `/g` is needed.  But what happens if string contains zero `,`s?

Answer (score 0):

This gives `null` because `'/[,]/i'` is not a regex. As explained at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), if a non-regex is passed to `string.match`, then it will be converted to a regex using `new Regex(obj)`.

What you want is to pass the actual regex object, `/[,]/i` (or simply `/,/i`). `"1,2,3".match(/,/i)` will work as you expect in terms of matching.

However, as Cybernate pointed out, a regex is overkill for this kind of problem. A better solution is to split the string:

```
var str = "1,2,3,4,5";
var len = str.split(",").length - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_occurrence(varS,string){//Find All Occurrences
    c=(string.split(varS).length - 1);
    return c;
}
string="Hi, 1,2,3";
console.log(get_occurrence(",",string));
```

Use get_occurrence(varS,string) to find occurrence of both characters and string in a String.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please do not add an answer that just repeats an already existing one. Instead, upvote the one that is already there. I know that for the moment you don't have enough rep for that (15), but in this case the best approach is to bookmark this page and, when you have enough rep, come back here and upvote. Otherwise, as frustrating as it may be (we've all been there!), just let it go. But please do not post an answer that doesn't add anything to what is already there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to divide some data using ',' from a statement:

```
 var str = "Stack,Overflow,best,for,coder"    
 var matchesCount = str.split(",").length;
 var vallueArray = str.split(',', matchesCount);
 var value1= "";
 for (var i = 0 ; i < vallueArray.length; i++) {
         value1= value1+ vallueArray [i] + " ";
    }
  document.getElementById("txt1").value = value1;
```