# Looping through arrays to check for patterns

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through an array to check for a specific pattern but keep getting no output afterwards. Not sure what I've done wrong! I would appreciate any help!

I am testing for the pattern at or hat.

```
sample = ["cat fat hat mat", "that the who"]
searchTerm = prompt("Testing?");

function count(sample, searchTerm) 
{

    for (i=0;i<sample.length;i++)
    {
    if (sample[i].indexOf(searchTerm) == -1) 
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return count(sample.substring(sample.indexOf(searchTerm) + searchTerm.length), searchTerm) + 1;
    }
}

alert(count(sample, searchTerm));
```

Rehashed code

```
search = ["cat fat hat mat", "that the who"];

var pattern = prompt('Search?'); 

function count(sample, searchTerm) 
{
    var count, i;
    count = 0;
    for (i=0; i < sample.length; i++)
    {
        if (sample[i].indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1) 
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

count(search, pattern);
```

I've redone everything and it still gives no output.

Comment: What pattern are you testing for? What's the overall goal?

Comment: I'm testing for the pattern "at".

Comment: You need to use an alert() or something else to display the result in your 'rehashed' code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with this code.  The most immediate one is you are calling `substring` on an `array` and not a `string`.

```
return count(sample.substring ...
```

Likely you meant to say

```
return count(sample[i].substring ...
```

The second issue though is that you need to divide the logic up a bit.  You need to divide it up into sections that count the occurrences in a word and that which iterates through the array.  Today they are intertwined and results in odd behavior because you end up passing non-arrays to places expecting arrays

```
function count(sample, searchTerm) {
  var num = 0;
  for (i=0;i<sample.length;i++) {
    var current = sample[i];
    var index = current.indexOf(searchTerm);
    while (index >= 0) {
      num++;
      index = current.indexOf(searchTerm, index + 1);
    }
  }
  return num;
}
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wrNbL/

Comment: I managed to get something done here [link(http://jsfiddle.net/CnREL/) but when I wrapped it in a for loop it horribly failed!

Comment: @jeansymolanza check the fiddle link i just posted to my answer. It has a working sample

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use recursion here, just iterate through the array once counting if the search term matches.

```
function count(sample, searchTerm) 
{
    var count, i;
    count = 0;
    for (i=0; i < sample.length; i++)
    {
        if (sample[i].indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1) 
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What if there are multiple matches of a specific pattern - would it count it all?

Comment: No, this only counts the number of elements in the array that contain the searchTerm.

Comment: How would I go about counting the amount of patterns within each array as I did here http://jsfiddle.net/CnREL/

Comment: Take a look at: [Count number of matches of a regex in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072765/count-number-of-matches-of-a-regex-in-javascript)