# Counting a spectific character in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
file123,file456,file789
```

I want to count the number of time "," is in this string
for example for this string the answer should be 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways you can do this, but here's a few examples :)

1.

```
"123,123,123".split(",").length-1
```

2.

```
("123,123,123".match(/,/g)||[]).length
```

Comment: which one return 0 in case of no match ?

Comment: Both of these return 0 if no match

Answer (score 3):

Simple regex will give you the length:

```
var str = "file123,file456,file789";
var count = str.match(/,/g).length;
```

Comment: I like this one, though it will generate an array of matches which is then discarded :)

Comment: @Jack So does `.split` and [this is a tiny bit faster](http://jsperf.com/count-occurences-of-string-in-string).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yeah, exec() (my answer) comes in at a [relatively close second](http://jsperf.com/count-occurences-of-string-in-string/3) :)

Comment: @Jack `exec()` is actually third for me with ~3K ops/sec where `split()` and `match()` have about ~4.5K ops/sec.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I meant second in the sense that both split() and match() are kind of the same thing :)

Comment: @Jack Oh yes, then I completely agree. It's definitely faster than iterating the string :)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yeah, vanilla iteration sucks... :'(

Comment: @thefourtheye I wonder why that is - perhaps js just isn't good at looking up characters in a string? Perhaps it's just V8 taking over a good part of the match/split functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`RegExp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to keep memory down if you're dealing with a big string:

```
var re = /,/g,
str = 'file123,file456,file789',
count = 0;

while (re.exec(str)) {
    ++count;
}

console.log(count);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/yafuwofo/2/) - [benchmark comparison](http://jsperf.com/count-occurences-of-string-in-string/3)

The performance lies about 20% below a solution that uses `String.match()` but it helps if you're concerned about memory.

#### Update

Less sexy, but faster still:

```
var count = 0,
pos = -1;

while ((pos = str.indexOf(',', pos + 1)) != -1) {
  ++count;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/yafuwofo/3/)

Comment: Why the downvote? Is my answer wrong / not useful in any way?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably quicker to split the string based on the item you want and then getting the length of the resulting array.

```
var haystack = 'file123,file456,file789';
var needle = ',';
var count = haystack.split(needle).length - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `split` has to create another array, I would recommend writing a helper function like this

```
function count(originalString, character) {
    var result = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < originalString.length; i += 1) {
        if (character == originalString.charAt(i)) {
            result +=1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: [It might have to create another array, but it's also very fast compared to this](http://jsperf.com/count-occurences-of-string-in-string). That said, your solution obviously uses less memory.

Comment: @h2ooooooo But this is the slowest. :'(

Comment: You could have taken advantage of `String.indexOf()` (second part of my answer) ... I guess it all comes down to reducing "userland" code as much as possible .. maybe :)

Comment: @Jack Thanks :) As you said, its best to rely on the builtin functions as much as possible it seems

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = "file123,file456,file789".split(",").length - 1;
```

Comment: If the string is very big, a big array has to be constructed.