# How I can do to check if a string contains a comma with a space using a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

The string contains a name, where the first part corresponds to the name and the second to the lastname.

The regular expression must verify these formats:

- **`"Surname1 Surname2, Name1 Name2"`**
- **`"Surname1, Name1 Name2 Surname2"`**

Invalid strings:

```
 "Surname1 Surname2 Name1 Name2" 
 "Surname1, Surname2, Name1 Name2"
 "Surname1 Surname2 Name1 Name2,"
```

I try the following: **`/([\w][\,][\s]{1}\b)/`**, but did not work

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Your regex works fine, just check if the match count is exactly equals 1

Comment: how I can verify that?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072765/count-number-of-matches-of-a-regex-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that verifies both cases:

This is the regular expression: `/\b\w+\s*\w*,\s\w+\s\w+\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*\s*\w*$\b/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/\b\w+\s+\w+\s*,\s*\w+\s+\w+\b/
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support numbers in the name like your example above.

```
var validName = function (name) {
  return /^\w+ \w+, \w+ \w+$/.test(name);
};
```

or if any kind of whitespace is allowed between names

```
validName = function (name) {
  return /^\w+\s\w+,\s\w+\s\w+$/.test(name);
},
```

or if you only want to allow US letters

```
validName = function (name) {
  return /^[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+, [A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+$/.test(name);
},
```