# Javascript search string using array

Tags: javascript, regex, search, match

I am trying to search the text of a body of a webpage against a list of predefined words in an array. Then record how many instances of each word appeared.

```
<script>
var str = document.body.innerText;
var array = [];
array[0] = "Statement";
array[1] = "Documents"; 
var regexp = new RegExp( '\\b' + array.join('\\b|\\b') + '\\b').test(str);
document.write(regexp)
</script>
```

That one is only returning true or false.
Or is there a way to make this one work?

```
var str = document.body.innerText;
var n = str.match(use array here)
document.write(n)
```

Comment: Try doing `var n = str.match(use array here).length;`

Comment: Also check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072765/count-number-of-matches-of-a-regex-in-javascript

Comment: Don't use non-standard `innerText`. Use `textContent`.

Comment: since when is `innerText` non-standard? [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText#Browser_Compatibility)

Comment: @NonPolynomial `innerText` used to be non-standard but things have changed now. Hate that MDN redirects you to their cheesy localized page rather than the English version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
n = str.match(new RegExp('\\b(' + arr.join('|') + ')\\b', 'ig')) || []).length;
```

1. make a dynamic Regex with `i` and `g` flag

   ```js
   new RegExp('\\b(' + arr.join('|') + ')\\b', 'ig')
   ```
2. define an empty array as fallback

   ```js
   str.match(regex) || []
   ```
3. return the length of the results array or the fallback array

   ```js
   str.match(new RegExp('\\b(' + arr.join('|') + ')\\b', 'ig')) || []).length;
   ```

Comment: I'm probably not skilled enough to implement this.
I thought it would be really easy. 
I will hit tutorials a bit more.