# Javascript regex to check for at least 3 carets in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am requesting assistance with a regular expression to show that there are at least 3 carets in a string. I've tried using `/\^/` but that only finds if the caret exists one time.

**Example Data**:

```
KEYWORD^HOSTNAME^MESSAGE^NUMBERS
```

Comment: And what regexes have you tried so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count number of matches of a regex in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072765/count-number-of-matches-of-a-regex-in-javascript)

Comment: /\^/ but that only finds if it exists one time. How can I add that the care  must be present 3 times in the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression should work:

```
(.*\^.*){3}
```

Example in javascript:

```
var str = "KEYWORD^HOSTNAME^MESSAGE^NUMBERS";
var patt = new RegExp(/(.*\^.*){3}/);
var res = patt.test(str);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I tried the expression that you provided but am receiving an invalid response.                                                                                           
                                                                                                          
var string = "KEYWORD^HOSTNAME^MESSAGE^NUMBERS";
var re = new RegExp("/.*(.*\^.*){3,}.*/");
if (re.test(string)) {
    console.log("Valid");
} else {
    console.log("Invalid");
}

Comment: @Dward RegExp(/(.*\^.*){3}/); without ' " '

Comment: @misanthrop Thanks  for improving the regex