# javascript to validate random characters in password like "a1a, aKa, a$a, aJ^lG, G78%s#

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a password change page where I want to validate my password with "2 small letters, 2 capital letters, 3 symbols, 2 digits and so on. Now from the below code I am able to just validate the password in sequence like "aa, KK,ap, JK, 90, 89" but not working for " aK9Ju, a^rtH, hGT5$u etc.

I am just pasting code for small letters, If you want I can provide the entire code.

```
psw.onkeyup = function() {
var LC = jsonData.LOWERCASE;
var psw = document.getElementById("psw").value.replace(/([a-z])\d+/g, '$1');
var lowerCaseLetters = new RegExp('[a-z]{' + LC + '}', 'g')
if(psw.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {
letter.classList.remove("invalid");
letter.classList.add("valid");
} else {
letter.classList.remove("valid");
letter.classList.add("invalid");
}
```

So, My requirement is what ever the way I put my password it should validate the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created you a working example with 3 restraints:
 - 2 small letters
 - 2 capital letters
 - 2 digits
if you need to add a constraint, yjust write a simple regex to match that single constraint, and connect it to the existing if statement via `&&`. I've used a function to count the number of occurences of regex matches from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072765/count-number-of-matches-of-a-regex-in-javascript).

```js
function testPassword(){
  var pw = document.getElementById("password").value;
  if ( count(pw, /[a-z]/g) > 1 &&
       count(pw, /[A-Z]/g) > 1 &&
       count(pw, /[0-9]/g) > 1 &&
       count(pw,/\W|_/g) > 1                     //special chars
     ){
        
        alert("success")
       
       
       }
        
}

const count = (str,pattern) => {
  const re = pattern
  return ((str || '').match(re) || []).length
}
```

```html
<input id="password" type="text">
<input type="submit" id="submit" onClick="testPassword()">
```

Comment: Found the answer, below code is working..

psw.onkeyup = function() {

  var LC = jsonData.LOWERCASE;
  var lowerCaseLetters = new RegExp('(?:[a-z].*){' + LC + '}', 'g')
  if(psw.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
  }